# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xdb in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I am loading a file using `pickle.load` at that time I am facing this error.

```
with open("tfidf_vectorizer", mode='r+b') as handle:                            
    tfidf_vectorizer = pickle.load(handle)
```

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xdb in position
>   0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: why is it that your file `tfidf_vectorizer` has no extension. Shouldn't it be something like `tfidf_vectorizer.json` or something like that @KlausD.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting an encoding when reading the file.

**Ex:**

```
with open("tfidf_vectorizer", mode='r+b', encoding='utf-8') as handle:                            
    tfidf_vectorizer = pickle.load(handle)
```